# Asynchronous loading of image in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous

I would like to refresh a cell where an asynchrone loading has been done.

I know 2 ways to do that but none is exactly what I want. Here is what I know:

```
[myTableView reloadData];
```

Or

```
 [myTableView beginUpdates];
 [myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathOfMyCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
 [myTableView endUpdates];
```

My asynchrone method to load images is called directly from my custom `UITableViewCell`. That means it's independent of my `UITableView`. The final solution I have is to pass the my `UITableViewCell` as parameter with the index on the current cell. It looks like a very ugly solution.

Does anyone know another solution ?

**Edit:**

```
[myCacheClass loadUIImageFromPath:photo.mediumDistURL];

loadUIImageFromPath:(NSString *) path{
  //Some code to load the image.
  if(![weakSelf.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(MyCacheDidLoadImageFromCache:)])
    [weakSelf setDelegate:appDelegate.callbacksCollector];
  [weakSelf.delegate MyCacheDidLoadImageFromCache:image];
 }
```

The implementation of `MyCacheDidLoadImageFromCache`:

```
- (void) CacheCacheDidLoadImageFromCache: (UIImage *) image{
  DDLogInfo(@"Successfully load image from cache : %@", [image description]);
  myImageView.image = image;
}
```

Comment: To clarify, do you want to update the cell once the asynchronous load has been completed, or do you want to re-load the cell after one asynchronous load has already been completed (ie. refresh an image that is already loaded)?

Comment: My problem is that my asynchronous method is called inside my cell (during the loading of the `UITableView`. I don't really want to pass my `UITableView` as parameter of my cell. That's why I'm asking if there is another way to do it.

Comment: So you are making an asynch call which grabs the image I'm guessing? And you want to display that image once the call has completed and on a per-cell basis right?

Comment: You're right for the asynch call. Then I have a callback method implemented on my custom cell that bring the loaded image. In this method I update a `UIView` on my custom cell.

Comment: @bobbystouket: try my approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the block based solution, no need to pass `tableView` and `indexPath` pointer to cell. We'll implement a `completionBlock` instead. You should be familiar with this type of approach:

**CustomCell.h:**

```
// Define block as a typedef
typedef void (^CellCompletionHandler)(BOOL);
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

// Take a predefined block as a parameter
- (void)initWithImageURL:(NSURL *)URL completionHanlder:(CellCompletionHandler)completion;

@end
```

**CustomCell.m:**

```
- (void)initWithImageURL:(NSURL *)URL completionHanlder:(CellCompletionHandler)completion
{
    // Take the URL and call cell's inner loading method
    // Pass the completion block to it
    [self doSomethingWithCellCompletionHandler:completion];
}

- (void)doSomethingWithCellCompletionHandler:(CellCompletionHandler)completion
{
    // When you finish loading your image from cache
    // call this to tell the block that you finished
    completion(YES);
}
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
[cell initWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your URL"]completionHanlder:^(BOOL finishedLoading) {
        if(finishedLoading)
        {
            // Here you can use indexPath to check whether it's visible
            // in order to reload it
            NSLog(@"Finished loading image");
        }

    }];
```

Comment: It's perfect. A bit complicated to try but it's ok ! I made the mistake to not check if the image was nil or not (=> high CPU activity and blinking images). If I check that before, everything is perfectly working. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of better solutions already defined for this type of situation. You can go for  sophisticated third party code [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView), [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Comment: My Asynchronous loading is already created and I think I'll have the same problem with others because the only missing point here is to refresh a current cell without passing the `UITableView` as parameter of my custom cell.

Comment: If you are loading inside your cell, why do you need a reference to your table view?  Can't you just update the image view in the cell (self) once the image has loaded?

Comment: @bobbystouket: I have the same question as Paul. Why can't cell update itself?

Comment: I don't know. Basically I thought that when I update an `UIView` anywhere is the visible area of the screen, this view should be updated. It's not the case. I need to scroll down and up to see my loaded images where they should be.

Answer (score 1):

You can indirect via [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  The table can subscribe notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(dataAvailableNotification:) 
    name:@"MyDataNowAvailable"
    object:nil];
```

When the data is available, the cache will post:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyDataNowAvailable" 
    object:self userInfo:@{@"Data": theData}];
```

Then the table reacts to this notification by mapping the data to appropriate cells and triggering the repaint:

```
- (void) dataAvailableNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    DataObject *theData = notification.userInfo[@"Data"];
    // add code here to find which cell(s) this data is displayed in
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    // etc
}
```

Good thing about this method is it generalizes to situations where you have the same data displayed in multiple views.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to pass `UITableViewCell`, instead past `NSIndexPath` for that perticular cell. & then use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` method to reload.

To obtain the table container in your chache class file use property.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UITableView *tableView;
```

Then in implemetation

```
loadUIImageFromPath:(NSString *) path forCell(NsIndexPath*)indexPath{
  //Some code to load the image.
  if(![weakSelf.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(MyCacheDidLoadImageFromCache:)])
    [weakSelf setDelegate:appDelegate.callbacksCollector];
  [weakSelf.delegate MyCacheDidLoadImageFromCache:image forCell:indexPath];
 }

- (void) CacheCacheDidLoadImageFromCache: (UIImage *) image forCell(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
  DDLogInfo(@"Successfully load image from cache : %@", [image description]);
  [tableView beginUpdates];
  [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
  [tableView endUpdates];
  myImageView.image = image;
  //tableView is from property & you have to pass NSIndexPath
}
```

& in your ViewController assign this propery as

```
myCacheClass.tableView = yourTableView;
[myCacheClass loadUIImageFromPath:photo.mediumDistURL forCell:indexPath];
```

Comment: `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` is a method of `UITableView`. My cell is doing the async call by itself. That means my cell needs to know the `UITableView` to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`. My `UITableView` doesn't know if the loading is finished or not.

Comment: @bobbystouket Could you show us Asynchronous Image loading code? So we might get a better idea of your problem.

Comment: I've added it to the main subject.

Comment: You have created a myCacheClass seperatly & loading image there. This code is seperate from your UIViewController code, am I right?

Comment: @rohanAM: he knew this approach beforehand but he does want a better solution.

Comment: :-) Your answer is what I had in mind but I'm not sure it is the best way to do. I don't like to pass as parameter the parent. Then you arrive to my question. Is there any other way to refresh my cell than `reloadData` or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` called from the `UITableView`.

Comment: @bobbystouket: I'm thinking of using a block based on celloading method, but your delegate makes me confused. Can you explain in details how does it flow to get your image fully loaded?

Comment: Basically I have the path of the wanted image. I'm calling my cache class to check if it's already in cache (Core Data). If not I ask to the cache class to download and store it. In both cases, after I've got the image I'm calling my callback method to send the image to the delegated class which implements `CacheCacheDidLoadImageFromCache`.

Comment: @bobbystouket As per your scenario this is what stuck to my mind as most appropriate answer, & NO.. no other way is coming to my mind to reload data other that 'reloadData' or 'reloadRowsAtIndexPaths' to refresh the 'UITableViewCell'.

Comment: @rohanAM: agreed but a nicer solution which passes not directly tableview into cell is what he's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`
 after you setup your subclassed TableViewCell.

```
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your image url"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

            if (imageData) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                if (image) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        YourCellSubclass *updateCell = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                        if (updateCell) {
                            updateCell.yourImageView.image = image;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

In this code, every cell makes an asynchronous image request as the cell is being loaded. If data comes back, it attempts to create a UIImage out of it. If that image is valid it then updates the image on the main thread only if the cell is still visible.

This code will make a network call for the image every time the cell is loaded. You will want to implement some sort of caching most likely. The type/amount of caching you want to do depends on how dynamic your data is.

Comment: I tried but I've still the same problem because the cell is not reloaded. It's perfectly working (like my method) when the images are hidden (not scroll down yet). After a scrolling up and down, every images are visible.